# Shader testgrid - lines jagged and breaking

Tags: java, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I need to write a simple shader for the testgrid ground surface. I want to basically draw parallel lines in shader code.

Problem: as the lines grow more distant from the camera, they begin to break up and there're gaps in them. I understand why that happens with my code - because OpenGL approximates fragment's position as being too far from the point that I calculate, so it marks it as not belonging to a line.

I am passing the actual world positions of the plane surface vectors to my shader - that's how I can calculate it.

I've been playing with the algorithm for an hour, but can't seem to get good results.

The best idea I've tried was to include a small coefficient that grows the further the line gets from the camera - but the results are underwhelming. I calculated the coefficient linearly, but I guess I need some smarter formula to go that route, because the rate at which the lines grow thinner on the screen isn't linear. I can't figure this out so far though. Currently it either makes close lines too thick, which is undesirable, or still has the same problem for distant lines.

To simplify, I'm currently only drawing X-axis lines

I'm including a piece of shader code and a screenshot of the problem.

```c
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;

in highp vec3 vertexPosition;

out mediump vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    highp float lineWidth = 0.2;
    highp float squareSize = 5.0f;

    highp int roundX = int(vertexPosition.x / squareSize);
    highp int roundY = int(vertexPosition.z / squareSize);
    highp float remainderX = vertexPosition.x - float(roundX)*squareSize;
    highp float remainderY = vertexPosition.x - float(roundY)*squareSize;

    // this is the small coefficient I was trying to add to linewidth
    highp float test = abs(0.08 * float(roundX));

    if (abs(remainderX) <= (lineWidth))
    {
        fragColor = vec4(1,0,0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        fragColor = vec4(0.8,0.8,0.8, 1);
    }
}
```

[image: Lines breaking up]

The first answer fixes the main problem with lines breaking, but introduces a visual bug. Gonna go and try to find out why. Anyway, this is already a good idea! But as you can see the lines get wider towards the end.

Edit: Found it. Just removed the Z coordinate from `vertexPosition` before doing `dFdy`. Now all I need it a way to make the lines smoother and not staircase-like.
[image: Visual bug after first answer's algorithm]

p.s. Don't look at how optimized the code is - I'm currently just searching for the right idea
p.p.s. If someone can tell me how to do simple antialiasing for this example - this also would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important that `roundX` is rounded ([`round`](http://docs.gl/el3/round)) to the nearest integer, rather than truncated:

```c
highp int roundX = int(round(vertexPosition.x / squareSize));
```

or

```c
highp int roundX = int(vertexPosition.x / squareSize + 0.5 * sign(vertexPosition.x));
```

A possible solution is to get the partial derivative of `vertexPosition.xy` along the y axis of the viewport by [`dFdy`](http://docs.gl/el3/dFdx).
The length of the partial derivative of `vertexPosition.xy` gives the distance between 2 fragments in model space. Thus the minimum thickness of a line can be defined:

```c
vec2 dy = dFdy(vertexPosition.xy);
float minWidth = length(dy);

float w = step(max(lineWidth, minWidth), abs(remainderX));
fragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), w);
```

For smoother lines, you have to interpolate the line color and the ground color. Interpolate if `abs(remainderX)` is between `min(lineWidth, minWidth)` and `max(lineWidth, minWidth)`. Use [`smoothstep`](http://docs.gl/el3/smoothstep) for the interpolation. e.g.:

```c
highp int roundX = int(round(vertexPosition.x / squareSize));
highp float remainderX = vertexPosition.x - float(roundX)*squareSize;

vec2 dy = dFdy(vertexPosition.xy);
float minWidth = length(dy);

float w = smoothstep(min(lineWidth, minWidth), max(lineWidth, minWidth), abs(remainderX));
fragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), w);
```

See the Three.js example, which uses the shader:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });

    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 300);
    camera.position.set(10, 15, -60);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(400, 10);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
    
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({  
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });
    material.extensions = {
      derivatives: true
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 0.1, 100 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function resize() { 
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
varying vec3 vertexPosition;
void main() {
    vertexPosition = position.zyx;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
precision highp float;

varying vec3 vertexPosition;

int round(float x)
{
  return int(x + 0.5 * sign(x));
}

void main(){
    vec4 fragColor;

    highp float lineWidth = 0.2;
    highp float squareSize = 5.0;

    highp int roundX = round(vertexPosition.x / squareSize);
    highp float remainderX = vertexPosition.x - float(roundX)*squareSize;
    
    vec2 dy = dFdy(vertexPosition.xy);
    float minWidth = length(dy);

    float w = smoothstep(min(lineWidth, minWidth), max(lineWidth, minWidth), abs(remainderX));
    //float w = step(max(lineWidth, minWidth), abs(remainderX));
    fragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0), w);

    gl_FragColor = fragColor;
}
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer seems to do the job, but it also introduces a visual bug. See update of the post for screenshot.

Comment: Edit: Found it. Just removed the Z coordinate from vertexPosition before doing dFdy. Now all I need it a way to make the lines smoother and not staircase-like.